# Encoding Issue on a while loop Python

Tags: python, hash, encoding

OK, so I'm trying to create  a small programme that creates a hash for each text input.

The first loop is fine, it gets the right hash, but after that it just keeps encoding something else and I'm unsure what. Which means a login system with hashes doesn't work.

Can someone help please!!!!

```
import hashlib
encoder = hashlib.md5()
while True:
    OString = input("Input some text here >")
    encoder.update(OString.encode())
    hashedString = encoder.hexdigest()
    print(hashedString)

    Ostring = None
    hashedString = None
```

Results:

```
Input some text here >leila
754f9968bf5f5f68d7dea029889b7415
Input some text here >leila
e0d1d4c285dda17ba6ca74a4dc85ebac
Input some text here >leila
419b5673f979911d3418472b105b6d3b
Input some text here >leila
71cf61a5ed5ebe751fdd1409928fe29d
Input some text here >leila
8149e3cc783fc400a7d26d63d5725536
Input some text here >leila
25c64d332128eb267f8d38f4140f19a3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution as follows:

```
while True:
    encoder = hashlib.md5()
    OString = input("Input some text here >")
    encoder.update(OString.encode())
    hashedString = encoder.hexdigest()
    print(hashedString)

    Ostring = None
    hashedString = None
```

Essentially you're rehashing the first value because `encoder = hashlib.md5()` object variable is outside of the while loop.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You have to instantiate fresh new md5 encoder every time because you would just append some string to the old string and get hash from their concatenation:

```
import hashlib
while True:
    OString = input("Input some text here >")
    encoder = hashlib.md5()
    encoder.update(OString.encode())
    hashedString = encoder.hexdigest()
    print(hashedString)

    Ostring = None
    hashedString = None
```